# Requisição AJAX no servidor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Requisição AJAX não funciona quando no servidor...localmente funciona normal...
alguém tem ideia do que pode ser ?

```
function SalvarPedido() {

    //Data
    var data = $("#Data").val();

    //Cliente
    var cliente = $("#Cliente").val();

    //Valor
    var valor = $("#Valor").val();

    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    var tokenadr = $('form[action="/Pedido/Create"] input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    var headers = {};
    var headersadr = {};
    headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;
    headersadr['__RequestVerificationToken'] = tokenadr;

    //Gravar
    var url = "/Pedido/Create";

    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , type: "POST"
        , datatype: "json"
        , headers: headersadr
        , data: { Id: 0, Data: data, Cliente: cliente, Valor: valor, __RequestVerificationToken: token }
        , success: function (data) {
            if (data.Resultado > 0) {
                ListarItens(data.Resultado);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Algum erro na consola? Poderá ser CORS, e nesse caso deve dar erro na consola... Esse url `var url = "/Pedido/Create";` éstá correto? não devia ter o endereço do servidor se é um pedido externo?

Comment: mas ele não chega nem seta os valores ali em cima nas variaveis...fica vazio tudo...

Comment: Podes dar resposta ás minhas 2 perguntas? `1:` algum erro na consola? `2:` o url está correto?

Comment: 1 - Não 2 - Sim

Comment: Agora apenas a requisição AJAX não está funcionando...